# dcl deploy : Build /scene in production mode failed

Tags: decentraland, decentraland-ecs

dcl deploy
secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version
× Build /scene in production mode failed
Error: `dcl deploy` Error: Error while building the project, run "dcl help deploy" for more info.

I get this error whenever I run "dcl deploy". Moreover, I tried it with --skip-build and it works fine though the --skip-build also show an error:

√ Building scene in production mode
√ Deployment structure created.
**× Invalid scene.json:  should NOT have additional properties**
You need to sign the content before the deployment:
√ Validating scene.json

Here are the screenshots:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UWrD.png)